# How to solve $\arctan{\sqrt{\frac{10-x}{x}} + \arccos\sqrt{\frac{10-x}{10}}}= \frac\pi{2}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Can you tell me if it is possible to solve $$\arctan{\sqrt{\frac{10-x}{x}} + \arccos\sqrt{\frac{10-x}{10}}}= \frac\pi{2}\ ?$$
[wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+arctan%28sqrt%28%2810-x%29%2Fx%29%29+%2Barcos%28sqrt%28%2810-x%29%2F10%29%29+%3D1.570796354) doesn't say it is not computable, but says there are *no real solutions*, whereas we know the solution is $x=1$

Any hints on how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: How did you know the solution is 1? I tried it on my calculator and I was surprised!

Comment: If $\tan t=\sqrt{(10-x)/x}$ and $t$ is in $(0,\pi/2)$ then $\tan^2t+1=10/x=1/\cos^2t$ hence $\cos t=\sqrt{x/10}$ and $\cos(\pi/2-t)=\sin t=\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}=\sqrt{1-x/10}$, thus every $x$ in $(0,10]$ solves this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=\sqrt{\frac{10-x}{x}}$, let $z=\sqrt{\frac{10-x}{10}}$. Take the cosine of both sides:

$$\cos\left(\arctan y+\arccos z\right)=0.$$
Apply the angle addition formula.
$$\cos(\arctan y)z-\sin(\arctan y)\sin(\arccos z)=0.$$
From the definition of trigonometric ratios, we know that $\cos(\arctan y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}$, $\sin(\arctan y)=\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}$, and $\sin(\arccos z)=\sqrt{1-z^2}$. This leaves us with
$$\frac{z}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}-\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}\sqrt{1-z^2}=0$$
$$z-y\sqrt{1-z^2}=0$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{10-x}{10}}-\sqrt{\frac{10-x}{x}}\sqrt{1-\frac{10-x}{10}}=0$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{10-x}{10}}-\sqrt{\frac{10-x}{x}}\sqrt{\frac{x}{10}}=0$$
$$0=0.$$

This equation boils down to a tautology, so every value of $x$ is a solution.

Comment: If the original equation were equal to anything else, we would get no real solutions.

Comment: And no complex solutions either.

Comment: It's because you entered a decimal approximation for pi/2 which is not exactly pi/2, so as I said above, there are no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $1$ is not the only solution. Every $x$ such that $0< x\leq10$ is a solution. To see this, observe that the equation models a right angle triangle with legs $\sqrt x$ and $\sqrt{10-x}$.

Comment: Set $x=5$ and they will be equal.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\arctan\sqrt{\dfrac{10-x}x}=y\  \ \ \ (1)$

$\implies 0\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$ as $\sqrt{\dfrac{10-x}x}\ge0$

$\dfrac{10-x}x=\tan^2y\iff x=10\cos^2y$

$\implies\sqrt{\dfrac{10-x}{10}}=+\sin y$ as $0\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies\arccos\sqrt{\dfrac{10-x}{10}}=\arccos(\sin y)=\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin(\sin y)$

$\implies\arccos\sqrt{\dfrac{10-x}{10}}=\dfrac\pi2-y\  \ \ \ (2)$ as $0\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

Use $(1),(2)$